# AWS Custom Resource ROLLBACK_FAILED because of a catch22-like situation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a Custom Resource which gets stuck in a catch22-like situation whenever a ROLLBACK occurs.

The code below is a simplified example of what my code is doing. In case of a create request, it creates a table, for delete it deletes, and in case of an update it compares the old properties with the new, and returns an error when one of the columns has a new value (column updates are not supported yet).

A problematic ROLLBACK_FAILED occurs when

1. [SOLVED] whenever a create request type fails (due to sql syntax error for example). In this case it will trigger a delete request for the ROLLBACK phase, but this request will fail because the table does not yet exist.
2. whenever a update request type fails due to a updated column value. In this case it will trigger a new update request for the ROLLBACK phase in which the `event.ResourceProperties` and `event.OldResourceProperties` are switched, which will still cause an error.

```go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cfn"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/rdsdataservice"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    lambda.Start(cfn.LambdaWrap(handler))
}

type properties struct {
    TableName string
    Columns   []struct {
        Name  string
        Value string
    }
}

func handler(ctx context.Context, event cfn.Event) (physicalResourceID string, data map[string]interface{}, err error) {
    prid := event.PhysicalResourceID
    if event.RequestType == cfn.RequestCreate {
        prid = strings.ReplaceAll(uuid.New().String(), "-", "")
    }

    var props properties
    b, _ := json.Marshal(event.ResourceProperties)
    json.Unmarshal(b, &props)

    rds := rdsdataservice.New(nil)

    if event.RequestType == cfn.RequestCreate {
        rds.ExecuteStatement(&rdsdataservice.ExecuteStatementInput{
            Sql: aws.String(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE TABLE %s", props.TableName)),
        })
    }

    if event.RequestType == cfn.RequestDelete {
        rds.ExecuteStatement(&rdsdataservice.ExecuteStatementInput{
            Sql: aws.String(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE TABLE %s", props.TableName)),
        })
    }

    if event.RequestType == cfn.RequestUpdate {
        var oldProps properties
        b, _ := json.Marshal(event.OldResourceProperties)
        json.Unmarshal(b, &oldProps)

        columns := map[string]string{}
        for _, column := range props.Columns {
            columns[column.Name] = column.Value
        }

        for _, column := range oldProps.Columns {
            if val, ok := columns[column.Name]; ok {
                if val != column.Value {
                    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("cannot change column type")
                }
            }
        }

        // Do some extra stuff here for adding/removing columns
    }
    return prid, nil, nil
}
```

I have thought of 2 possible solutions. One of them I could implement, with potential issues. But it seems to me there should be a better way, as I can't be the only one with this problem. Or I am doing something very wrong..

1. disable rollback for this specific resource only, in some cases (sometimes I still want a rollback)
2. have access to the last status, so that I can check what to do; in case of delete with last status CREATE_FAILED, don't do anything. In case of an update with last status UPDATE_FAILED, don't do anything.

The second option I could implement by using the code below. But as the number of events grow, this could become very problematic.

```go
events, err := cloud.DescribeStackEvents(&cloudformation.DescribeStackEventsInput{
    StackName: &event.StackID,
})
```

Comment: For the DELETE failure, at least, you can use `drop table if exists`.

Comment: Fair enough. I could have thought of that myself. Actually, I did before, for some reason I deleted that and didn't think of that anymore.

But thanks for the reminder! This, however, indeed only solves the delete failure.

Comment: That's one reason it wasn't an answer ;-) Unfortunately, I don't think there _are_ any good answers. The best solution [that I came up with](https://github.com/kdgregory/cf-postgres) was to do extensive integration tests outside of CloudFormation and then cross your fingers that you've covered all the conditions. You'll note that project is only partly done, and may end up abandoned.

Comment: Well, after a very frustrating day with this issue, the reminder for `drop table if exists` was very welcome. Regarding the `update` issue, for now I solved it by checking if any of the last 3 stack statuses was `rollback_in_progress`. It works for now, but a better solution is still very welcome.

Comment: If this is primarily a development-time issue, you could have the Lambda look for an environment variable (maybe named `ALWAYS_SUCCESSFUL`), and if set always return a Success response. That will keep CloudFormation happy while you solve the actual problem.

Comment: Actually I do really want to send a `UPDATE_FAILED` response. If I return `UPDATE_COMPLETE` the entire stack would build and I have no way of knowing if the table actually updated or not. So, the resource should fail, but on rollback it should just not do a normal update (or not do a rollback for this resource at all).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into the same problem; I have solved this issue by looking at the stack events, and find the last resource status that is being updated. As the current status is always in the list, I ignore `IN_PROGRESS` values. If the first value after status `IN_PROGRESS` is `FAILED`, it means this resource could not be updated, and thus a different ROLLBACK strategie can be applied.

The corresponding function, in GO

```go
func isFailedEvent(sess *session.Session, event cfn.Event) (bool, error) {
    cloud := cloudformation.New(sess)
    var isFailedResource bool
    if err := cloud.DescribeStackEventsPages(&cloudformation.DescribeStackEventsInput{
        StackName: aws.String(event.StackID),
    }, func(out *cloudformation.DescribeStackEventsOutput, lastPage bool) bool {
        for _, e := range out.StackEvents {
            if *e.LogicalResourceId == event.LogicalResourceID {
                if strings.HasSuffix(*e.ResourceStatus, "IN_PROGRESS") {
                    continue
                }
                if strings.HasSuffix(*e.ResourceStatus, "FAILED") && !strings.Contains(*e.ResourceStatusReason, "cancelled") {
                    isFailedResource = true
                }
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }); err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("describe stack events: %s", err)
    }
    return isFailedResource, nil
}
```